# Django allauth: disable form login/signup

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-login, django-allauth

I'd like to know if anyone know if it's possible to completely disable form login/signup in [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).

In my business model, the user can only login/signup using Facebook, but whenever I use the @login_required decorator, it redirects the user to a login page where he can input email/password.

I couldn't find anything in the docs, so I thought I should ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom login page that only has the FB link on it.  You then define the path to the page in your settings file as your LOGIN_URL.

Comment: I think that would be quite ugly and considered a workaround. As I see, the best behavior would be redirecting the user to the "facebook_login" URL when the user is not authenticated. I'm still working on it and trying to solve this. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you do it this way, standard login page on /accounts/login/ will be still available? If so, if has a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed that for twitter, so I put the login url directly in the link for sign-up. Like so:

```
<a href="/accounts/twitter/login/">Sign In</a>
```